# Extracting parameters from strings - SQL Server

Tags: python, c#, sql, sql-server, excel

I have a table with strings in one column, which are actually storing other SQL Queries written before and stored to be ran at later times. They contain parameters such as '@organisationId' or '@enterDateHere'. I want to be able to extract these.

Example:

| ID | Query |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @organisationId |
| 2 | SELECT * FROM topic WHERE creation_time <=@startDate AND creation_time >= @endDate AND id = @enterOrgHere |
| 3 | SELECT name + '@' + domain FROM user |

I want the following:

| ID | Parameters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | @organisationId |
| 2 | @startDate, @endDate, @enterOrgHere |
| 3 | NULL |

No need to worry about how to separate/list them, as long as they are clearly visible and as long as the query lists all of them, which I don't know the number of. Please note that sometimes the queries contain just @ for example when email binding is being done, but it's not a parameter. I want just strings which start with @ and have at least one letter after it, ending with a non-letter character (space, enter, comma, semi-colon). If this causes problems, then return all strings starting with @ and I will simply identify the parameters manually.

It can include usage of Excel/Python/C# if needed, but SQL is preferable.

Comment: Just build an appropriate regular expression. You can do it in any language from your list.

Comment: Looks like a simple regular expression: `@\w+`. In Python: `matches = re.findall(r'@\w+', your_sql_string)`.

Comment: prolly OP doesn't wana catch something like  `name + '@example.' + domain` ... but there is more ... hehe what about `SELECT 1  FROM WHERE /* @example = 1 AND */  1 = 1` ... **just use some SQL parser ...**

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Why do you want this? It matters. SQL in general and T-SQL in particular are very bad at text parsing. It's better to use a parser like eg python-sqlparse. In SQL Server 2017 and later you can use Python scripts with `sp_execute_external_script` to process data using Python

Answer (score 2):

The official way to interrogate the parameters is with [sp_describe_undeclared_parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-undeclared-parameters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), eg

```
exec sp_describe_undeclared_parameters @tsql =  N'SELECT * FROM topic WHERE creation_time <=@startDate AND creation_time >= @endDate AND id = @enterOrgHere'
```

Comment: The best and most correct method, but requires correct code because the code is compiled

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to implement by using tokenization via XML and XQuery.

Notable points:

1. 1st `CROSS APPLY` is tokenazing Query column as XML.
2. 2nd `CROSS APPLY` is filtering out tokens that don't have "@" symbol.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Query VARCHAR(2048));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Query) VALUES
('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @organisationId'),
('SELECT * FROM topic WHERE creation_time <=@startDate AND creation_time >= @endDate AND id = @enterOrgHere'),
('SELECT name + ''@'' + domain FROM user');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT t.ID
    , Parameters = IIF(t2.Par LIKE '@[a-z]%', t2.Par, NULL)
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(Query, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRIM('><=' FROM c.query('data(/root/r[contains(text()[1],"@")])').value('text()[1]','VARCHAR(1024)'))) AS t2(Par)
```

**SQL #2**

A cleansing step was added to handle other than a regular **space** whitespaces first.

```
SELECT t.*
    , Parameters = IIF(t2.Par LIKE '@[a-z]%', t2.Par, NULL)
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<r><![CDATA[' + Query + ']]></r>' AS XML).value('(/r/text())[1] cast as xs:token?','VARCHAR(MAX)')) AS t0(pure)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(Pure, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRIM('><=' FROM c.query('data(/root/r[contains(text()[1],"@")])')
                .value('text()[1]','VARCHAR(1024)'))) AS t2(Par);
```

**Output**

| ID | Parameters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | @organisationId |
| 2 | @startDate @endDate @enterOrgHere |
| 3 | NULL |

Comment: That's not what anyone would call "simple"

Comment: This one didn't work unfortunately. It returned me things like "@orgId >=@fromDate <=@toDate", "table.organisationId=@organisationId" and also "@organisationId ORDER" picking up SQL keywords and other symbols in most cases

Comment: As I commented earlier, please provide a minimal reproducible example:  ##1-4 We can work off just what is provided.

Comment: Also, my answer is based on tokenization where space is used as a separator between tokens. Very possible that your Query column contains other whitespace characters.

Comment: Please try **SQL #2**

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer. It is still inaccurate, missing out on a lot of parameters, although it does return better results on some records. I have realised that the actual (elegant) solution for this is extracting through Python using regex, because SQL methods don't allow for generalisation and every single separator would have to be considered. The downsize is that I will have to do this manually on the table extracted from the database, unfortunately.

Comment: Please provide #1 from the minimal reproductive example

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server for parsing is a very bad idea because of low performance and lack of tools. I highly recommend using .net assembly or external language (since your project is in python anyway) with regexp or any other conversion method.
However, as a last resort, you can use something like this extremely slow and generally horrible code (this code working just on sql server 2017+, btw. On earlier versions code will be much more terrible):

```
DECLARE @sql TABLE
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
, sql_query NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @sql (sql_query)
VALUES (N'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @organisationId')
     , (N'SELECT * FROM topic WHERE creation_time <=@startDate AND creation_time >= @endDate AND id = @enterOrgHere')
     , (N'  SELECT name + ''@'' + domain FROM user')
     ;


WITH prepared AS
(
  SELECT id
        , IIF(sql_query LIKE '%@%'
             , SUBSTRING(sql_query, CHARINDEX('@', sql_query) + 1, LEN(sql_query))
             , CHAR(32)
             ) prep_string
    FROM @sql
),
parsed AS
(
SELECT id
     , IIF(CHARINDEX(CHAR(32), value) = 0
          , SUBSTRING(value, 1, LEN(VALUE))
          , SUBSTRING(value, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(32), value) -1)
          ) parsed_value
  FROM prepared p
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(p.prep_string, '@')
)
SELECT id, '@' + STRING_AGG(IIF(parsed_value LIKE '[a-zA-Z]%', parsed_value, NULL) , ', @')
  FROM parsed
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: This one also didn't work unfortunately. For example for a query which is just 'SELECT * FROM generic_table_name' it returned '@SELECT'. And it picks up SQL keywords too like '@parameter1' ORDER from an ORDER BY clause, although there is a space after it in the original query.

Comment: Yeah, another reason not to try parsing in SQL is edge cases. Changed the code for this case.

Comment: In general, the most reliable and simple way is to loop through the line. But I hate this method, so I don't give this example

Answer (score 0):

You can use string split, and then remove the undesired caracters, here's a query :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP

SELECT 1 AS ID ,'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @organisationId' AS Query
INTO #TEMP
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'SELECT * FROM topic WHERE creation_time <=@startDate AND creation_time >= @endDate AND id = @enterOrgHere'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'SELECT name + ''@'' + domain FROM user'

;WITH cte as
(
    SELECT ID,
        Query,
        STRING_AGG(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(value,'<',''),'>',''),'=',''),', ') AS Parameters
    FROM #TEMP
    CROSS APPLY string_split(Query,' ')
    WHERE value LIKE '%@[a-z]%'
    GROUP BY ID,
        Query
)
SELECT #TEMP.*,cte.Parameters
FROM #TEMP
LEFT JOIN cte on #TEMP.ID = cte.ID
```

Comment: This one also didn't work unfortunately. It picks up SQL keywords like '@insertIdHere ORDER' from a following ORDER BY clause, even though there is a space between them. And it picks up more text before and after the parameter in other scenarios.